# awk set variable to line after if statement match

Tags: awk

I have the following text...

```
BIOS Information
Manufacturer               : Dell Inc.
Version                    : 2.5.2
Release Date               : 01/28/2015

Firmware Information
Name                       : iDRAC7
Version                    : 2.21.21 (Build 12)

Firmware Information
Name                       : Lifecycle Controller 2
Version                    : 2.21.21.21
```

... which is piped into the following awk statement...

```
awk '{ if ($1" "$2 == "BIOS Information") var=$1} END { print var }'
```

This will output 'BIOS' in this case.
I want to look for 'BIOS Information' and then set the third field, two lines down, so in this case 'var' would equal '2.5.2'.  Is there a way to do this with awk?

EDIT:
I tried the following:

```
awk ' BEGIN {
FS="[ \t]*:[ \t]*";
}
NF==1 {
  sectname=$0;
}
NF==2 && $1 == "Version" && sectname="BIOS Information" {
  bios_version=$2;
}
END {
  print bios_version;
}'
```

Which gives me '2.21.21.21' with the above text.  Can this be modified to give me the first 'Version" following "BIOS Information"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following script may be an overkill but it is robust in cases if you have multiple section names and/or order of fields is changed.

```
BEGIN {
  FS="[ \t]*:[ \t]*";
}
NF==1 {
  sectname=$0;
}  
NF==2 && $1 == "Version" && sectname=="BIOS Information" {
  bios_version=$2;
} 
END {
  print bios_version;
}
```

First, we set input field separator so that words are not separated into different fields. Next, we check whether current line is section name or a key-value pair. If it is section name, set `sectname` to section name. If it is a key-value pair and current section name is "BIOS Information" and key is "Version" then we set `bios_version`.

Comment: Tried it which gives me the Version for the wrong section.  I just added a more complete section of text which im processing.  Thanks!

Comment: Fixed. There was missing equal sign here: `sectname=="BIOS Information"`.

Comment: Works great and I can expand on this, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**To answer the question as asked**:

```
awk -v RS= '
/^BIOS Information\n/ {
   for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) { if ($i=="Version") { var=$(i+2); exit } }
}
END { print var }
' file
```

- `-v RS=` puts `awk` in paragraph mode, so that each run of non-empty lines becomes a single record.
- `/^BIOS Information\n/` then only matches a record (paragraph) whose first line equals "BIOS Information".
- Each paragraph is internally still split into fields by any run of whitespace (`awk`'s default behavior), so the `for` loop loops over all fields until it finds literal `Version`, assigns the *2nd* field after it to a variable (because `:` is parsed as a separate field) and exits, at which point the variable value is printed in the `END` block.

  - Note: A more robust and complete way to extract the version number can be found in the update below (the field-looping approach here could yield false positives and also only ever reports the *first* (whitespace-separated) token of the version field).

---

**Update**, based on requirements that emerged later:

To act on *each* paragraph's version number and create *individual variables*:

```
awk -v RS= '

  # Helper function that that returns the value of the specified field.
  function getFieldValue(name) {
    # Split the record into everything before and after "...\n<name>   : "   
    # and the following \n; the 2nd element of the array thus created
    # then contains the desired value.
    split($0, tokens, "^.*\n" name "[[:blank:]]+:[[:blank:]]+|\n")
    return tokens[2]
  }  

  /^BIOS Information\n/ {
     biosVer=getFieldValue("Version")
     print "BIOS version = " biosVer
  }

  /^Firmware Information\n/ {
    firmVer=getFieldValue("Version")
    print "Firmware version (" getFieldValue("Name") ") = " firmVer 
  }

' file
```

With the sample input, this yields:

```
BIOS version = 2.5.2
Firmware version (iDRAC7) = 2.21.21 (Build 12)
Firmware version (Lifecycle Controller 2) = 2.21.21.21
```

Comment: That works perfectly, expanding on the question. Since i'm not using if statements in this.  How can i get the output of all three versions in the above text? as variables?

Comment: This works but I am unable to reference the variables unless i know where they fall.  qudok's version is a bit more ungraceful but it lets me set individual variable names and reference them later.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$ echo "$txt"
BIOS Information
Manufacturer               : Dell Inc.
Version                    : 2.5.2
Release Date               : 01/28/2015

Firmware Information
Name                       : iDRAC7
Version                    : 2.21.21 (Build 12)

Firmware Information
Name                       : Lifecycle Controller 2
Version                    : 2.21.21.21
```

You can do:

```
$ echo "$txt" | awk '/^BIOS Information/{f=1; printf($0)} /^Version/ && f{f=0; printf(":%s\n", $3)}'
BIOS Information:2.5.2
```